# unable to add foreign key constraint to previously created child table

Tags: mysql, constraints

So I have an error where I am unable to create a table then and then add a foreign key constraint to the table. the error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fridge_contents_database`.`#sql-21e8_a`, CONSTRAINT `P_FI_id` FOREIGN KEY (`FI_id`) REFERENCES `food_item` (`FI_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

I'm not sure what this means as there should be no previous foreign key that should be overriding this. here is my script up until this failed operation.

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS fridge_contents_database;
CREATE SCHEMA fridge_contents_database;
USE fridge_contents_database;

drop table if exists Food_Item;
create table Food_Item(
    FI_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FI_name varchar(50),
    FI_exp_date date,
    FG_id int,

    CONSTRAINT FI_id_PK PRIMARY KEY(FI_id)
);
INSERT INTO Food_Item (FI_name, FI_exp_date, FG_id) VALUES 
    ("Mayo", "2020-01-06", 3),
    ("Tofu","2020-01-15", 2),
    ("Courtland Apples", NULL, 2),
    ("Sandwich Pickles","2020-02-19", 2),
    ("Apple Sauce","2020-02-22", 2),
    ("Campbelle's Garden Vegetable Soup","2020-02-24", 2),
    ("Angel Food Cakes","2020-02-24", 5);

drop table if exists Pricing;
create table Pricing(
    FI_id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    P_priced_by varchar(10),
    P_price decimal(6,2), 

    constraint FI_id_PK primary key(FI_id)

);
insert into Pricing (FI_id, P_priced_by, P_price) values
(  1, "unit", 6.99  ),
(  2, "unit", 5.99 ),
(  3, "lb", 2.99 ),
(  4, "unit", 2.99 ),
(  5, "unit", 4.99 ),
(  6, "unit", 3.99 ),
(  7, "unit", 3.99 ),
(  8, "unit", 3.99 );


alter table Pricing
    add constraint P_FI_id foreign key (FI_id) references Food_Item (FI_id) on delete cascade;
```

I have tried quite a few things so far, including ensuring the field values are of the same type, and that both key have the exact same number of values.

Comment: There exists some record in child table which do not match FK condition. Find it/them and delete/edit.

Comment: Looking on the code. 1) 8 different non-NULL `FI_id` values in slave cannot match the main table which have only 7 records even on theory. 2) The code may insert into `Food_Item` the records with `FI_id` values other than 1..7.

Comment: Can't believe I missed this. thank you so much. this has stalled me for more than a day now